# Why is one of Maxwell's equations named after Ampère? Who first named it after Ampère?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, terminology, history

Ampère never wrote down what is confusingly called "[*Ampère*'s circuital law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re's_circuital_law)," not even the form without the displacement current term, as Ampère never dealt with the field concept.* Maxwell derived

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0\mathbf{J}\qquad(1)$$

in his 1855 paper [*On Faraday's Lines of Force*](https://archive.org/stream/scientificpapers01maxw#page/n193/mode/2up), based on analogies to hydrodynamics, which he corrected to be

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0\left(\mathbf{J} + \varepsilon_0 \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{E}} {\partial t} \right)\qquad(2)$$

in his 1861 paper [*On Physical Lines of Force*](https://archive.org/stream/scientificpapers01maxw#page/450/mode/2up); he never wrote down [Ampère's force law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re's_force_law) in either paper.

[Ampère's force law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re's_force_law) is completely different from any of Maxwell's equations. It gives the force that current elements $I_1 d\vec {\ell }_1$ and
$I_2 d\vec {\ell }_2$ exert on one another to be:

$$d^2\vec{F_{21}^A} = - \frac{\mu _0 }{4\pi }I_1 I_2 \frac{\hat {r}_{12} }{r_{12}^2 }\left[2(d\vec {\ell }_1 \cdot d\vec {\ell }_2) - 3({\hat {r}_{12} \cdot d\vec {\ell }_1 })({\hat {r}_{12} \cdot d\vec {\ell }_2 })\right] = - d^2\vec{F_{12}^A}.$$

Thus, it is appropriate that Equation (2) is one of *Maxwell*'s equations. Gauss and Faraday utilized the field concept, thus Equation (2) is the most "Maxwellian" of the four Maxwell's equations.

So, **why are Equations (1) & (2) above named after Ampère? Who first named it after Ampère?**

---

<sup>*cf. Assis, André Koch Torres; Chaib, J. P. M. C; Ampère, André-Marie (2015). *[Ampère's electrodynamics: analysis of the meaning and evolution of Ampère's force between current elements, together with a complete translation of his masterpiece: Theory of electrodynamic phenomena, uniquely deduced from experience](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/Amperes-Electrodynamics.pdf)* (PDF). Montreal: Apeiron. ISBN 978-1-987980-03-5. ch. 15 pp. 221ff.</sup>

Comment: This seems to me to be a question for [hsm.se] as it is purely a historical question with little bearing on physics. Interesting, for sure, but it's a question for a historian.

Comment: Crossposted to http://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/5059/1945